# Lyapunov exponents spectrum for a 3 D system

Tags: numpy, scipy, vectorization, chaos

I Have been searching for a Python code to compute Lyapunov exponents and finally found a code [LyapunovExponets](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/%7Echaos/courses/nlp/Software/PartH_Code/LorenzODELCE.p) but it is very long and not vectorized and not using python 3 and ODE solvers. I need help to vectorize it and use solv_ivp instead of the one used.

I intend to use this code for my model which is also 3D ODE system but It is almost impossible to understand this code or modify it to be applicable to general 3 D ODE system.I also want to be able to use different ODE solvers because RK method doesn't work for all problems. The code is also very long so I want it to be more compact and of course speed it up. This would be also good for other people who  study dynamical systems. There are of course Matlab codes that calculate lyapunov exponents but I want to have a code in a open source language.

```
# LorenzODELCE.py:
#   Estimate the spectrum of Lyapunov Characteristic Exponents
#  for the Lorenz ODEs, using the pull-back method.
#   Also, estimate the volume-contraction (dissipation) rate and the
#   fractal dimenion (latter using the Kaplan-Yorke conjecture).
#   Plot out trajectory, for reference.
#
# Comment:
#Notice how much more complicated the code has become, given
#that we're writing out variables in component form.
#   This should be rewritten to use vectors, which will be
#  much more compact and easier to debug. Equally important,
#      the code would generalize to any dimension system.

# Import plotting routines
from pylab import *

# The Lorenz 3D ODEs
#Original parameter values: (sigma,R,b) = (10,28,-8/3)
def LorenzXDot(sigma,R,b,x,y,z):
    return sigma * (-x + y)

def LorenzYDot(sigma,R,b,x,y,z):
    return R*x - x*z - y

def LorenzZDot(sigma,R,b,x,y,z):
    return -b*z + x*y

# The tangent space (linearized) flow (aka co-tangent flow)
def LorenzDXDot(sigma,R,b,x,y,z,dx,dy,dz):
    return sigma * (-dx + dy)

def LorenzDYDot(sigma,R,b,x,y,z,dx,dy,dz):
    return (R-z)*dx - dy - x*dz

def LorenzDZDot(sigma,R,b,x,y,z,dx,dy,dz):
    return y*dx + x*dy + b*dz

# Volume contraction given by
#    Trace(Jacobian(x,y,z)) = b - sigma - 1
def LorenzODETrJac(sigma,R,b,x,y,z):
    return b - sigma - 1
# As a check, we must have total contraction = Sum of LCEs
#    Tr(J) = Sum_i LCEi
# Numerical check: at (sigma,R,b) = (10,28,-8/3)
#    LCE0  ~   0.9058
#    LCE1  ~   0.0000
#    LCE2  ~ -14.572
#    Tr(J) ~ -13.6666
# These use base-2 logs

# The fractal dimension from the LCEs (Kaplan-Yorke conjecture)
#   Assume these are ordered: LCE1 >= LCE2 >= LCE3
def FractalDimension3DODE(LCE1,LCE2,LCE3):
    # "Close" to zero ... we're estimating here
    Err = 0.01
    if LCE1 < -Err:   # Stable fixed point    (-,-,-)
        return 0.0
    elif abs(LCE1) <= Err:
        if LCE2 < -Err:  # Limit cycle        (0,-,-)
            return 1.0
        else:           # Torus               (0,0,-)
            return 2.0
    else:               # Chaotic attractor   (+,0,-)
        return 2.0 + (LCE1+LCE2) / abs(LCE3)

# 3D fourth-order Runge-Kutta integrator
def RKThreeD(a,b,c,x,y,z,f,g,h,dt):
    k1x = dt * f(a,b,c,x,y,z)
    k1y = dt * g(a,b,c,x,y,z)
    k1z = dt * h(a,b,c,x,y,z)
    k2x = dt * f(a,b,c,x + k1x / 2.0,y + k1y / 2.0,z + k1z / 2.0)
    k2y = dt * g(a,b,c,x + k1x / 2.0,y + k1y / 2.0,z + k1z / 2.0)
    k2z = dt * h(a,b,c,x + k1x / 2.0,y + k1y / 2.0,z + k1z / 2.0)
    k3x = dt * f(a,b,c,x + k2x / 2.0,y + k2y / 2.0,z + k2z / 2.0)
    k3y = dt * g(a,b,c,x + k2x / 2.0,y + k2y / 2.0,z + k2z / 2.0)
    k3z = dt * h(a,b,c,x + k2x / 2.0,y + k2y / 2.0,z + k2z / 2.0)
    k4x = dt * f(a,b,c,x + k3x,y + k3y,z + k3z)
    k4y = dt * g(a,b,c,x + k3x,y + k3y,z + k3z)
    k4z = dt * h(a,b,c,x + k3x,y + k3y,z + k3z)
    x += ( k1x + 2.0 * k2x + 2.0 * k3x + k4x ) / 6.0
    y += ( k1y + 2.0 * k2y + 2.0 * k3y + k4y ) / 6.0
    z += ( k1z + 2.0 * k2z + 2.0 * k3z + k4z ) / 6.0
    return x,y,z

# Tanget space flow (using fourth-order Runge-Kutta integrator)
def TangentFlowRKThreeD(a,b,c,x,y,z,df,dg,dh,dx,dy,dz,dt):
    k1x = dt * df(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)
    k1y = dt * dg(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)
    k1z = dt * dh(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)
    k2x = dt * df(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k1x/2.0,dy+k1y/2.0,dz+k1z/2.0)
    k2y = dt * dg(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k1x/2.0,dy+k1y/2.0,dz+k1z/2.0)
    k2z = dt * dh(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k1x/2.0,dy+k1y/2.0,dz+k1z/2.0)
    k3x = dt * df(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k2x/2.0,dy+k2y/2.0,dz+k2z/2.0)
    k3y = dt * dg(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k2x/2.0,dy+k2y/2.0,dz+k2z/2.0)
    k3z = dt * dh(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k2x/2.0,dy+k2y/2.0,dz+k2z/2.0)
    k4x = dt * df(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k3x,dy+k3y,dz+k3z)
    k4y = dt * dg(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k3x,dy+k3y,dz+k3z)
    k4z = dt * dh(a,b,c,x,y,z,dx+k3x,dy+k3y,dz+k3z)
    dx += ( k1x + 2.0 * k2x + 2.0 * k3x + k4x ) / 6.0
    dy += ( k1y + 2.0 * k2y + 2.0 * k3y + k4y ) / 6.0
    dz += ( k1z + 2.0 * k2z + 2.0 * k3z + k4z ) / 6.0
    return dx,dy,dz

# Simulation parameters
# Integration time step
dt = 0.01
#
# Control parameters for the Lorenz ODEs:
sigma = 10.0
R     = 28.0
b     = -8.0/3.0
# The number of iterations to throw away
nTransients = 10
# The number of time steps to integrate over
nIterates = 1000

# The main loop that generates the orbit, storing the states
xState = 5.0
yState = 5.0
zState = 5.0
# Iterate for some number of transients, but don't use these states
for n in range(0,nTransients):
    xState,yState,zState = RKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,LorenzXDot,LorenzYDot,LorenzZDot,dt)
# Set up array of iterates and store the current state
x = [xState]
y = [yState]
z = [zState]
for n in range(0,nIterates):
    # at each time step calculate new (x,y,z)(t)
    xt,yt,zt = RKThreeD(sigma,R,b,x[n],y[n],z[n],LorenzXDot,LorenzYDot,LorenzZDot,dt)
    # and append to lists
    x.append(xt)
    y.append(yt)
    z.append(zt)

# Estimate the LCEs
# The number of iterations to throw away
nTransients = 100
# The number of iterations to over which to estimate
#  This is really the number of pull-backs
nIterates = 10000
# The number of iterations per pull-back
nItsPerPB = 10
# Initial condition
xState = 5.0
yState = 5.0 
zState = 5.0 
# Initial tangent vectors
e1x = 1.0
e1y = 0.0
e1z = 0.0
e2x = 0.0
e2y = 1.0
e2z = 0.0
e3x = 0.0
e3y = 0.0
e3z = 1.0
# Iterate away transients and let the tangent vectors align
#   with the global stable and unstable manifolds
for n in range(0,nTransients):
    for i in range(nItsPerPB):
        xState,yState,zState = RKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzXDot,LorenzYDot,LorenzZDot,dt)
        # Evolve tangent vector for maximum LCE (LCE1)
        e1x,e1y,e1z = TangentFlowRKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzDXDot,LorenzDYDot,LorenzDZDot,e1x,e1y,e1z,dt)
        # Evolve tangent vector for next LCE (LCE2)
        e2x,e2y,e2z = TangentFlowRKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzDXDot,LorenzDYDot,LorenzDZDot,e2x,e2y,e2z,dt)
        # Evolve tangent vector for last LCE
        e3x,e3y,e3z = TangentFlowRKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzDXDot,LorenzDYDot,LorenzDZDot,e3x,e3y,e3z,dt)
    # Normalize the tangent vector
    d = sqrt(e1x*e1x + e1y*e1y + e1z*e1z)
    e1x /= d
    e1y /= d
    e1z /= d
    # Pull-back: Remove any e1 component from e2
    dote1e2 = e1x * e2x + e1y * e2y + e1z * e2z
    e2x -= dote1e2 * e1x
    e2y -= dote1e2 * e1y
    e2z -= dote1e2 * e1z
    # Normalize second tangent vector
    d = sqrt(e2x*e2x + e2y*e2y + e2z*e2z)
    e2x /= d
    e2y /= d
    e2z /= d
    # Pull-back: Remove any e1 and e2 components from e3
    dote1e3 = e1x * e3x + e1y * e3y + e1z * e3z
    dote2e3 = e2x * e3x + e2y * e3y + e2z * e3z
    e3x -= dote1e3 * e1x + dote2e3 * e2x
    e3y -= dote1e3 * e1y + dote2e3 * e2y
    e3z -= dote1e3 * e1z + dote2e3 * e2z
    # Normalize third tangent vector
    d = sqrt(e3x*e3x + e3y*e3y + e3z*e3z)
    e3x /= d
    e3y /= d
    e3z /= d

# Okay, now we're ready to begin the estimation
LCE1 = 0.0
LCE2 = 0.0
LCE3 = 0.0
for n in range(0,nIterates):
    for i in range(nItsPerPB):
        xState,yState,zState = RKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzXDot,LorenzYDot,LorenzZDot,dt)
        # Evolve tangent vector for maximum LCE (LCE1)
        e1x,e1y,e1z = TangentFlowRKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzDXDot,LorenzDYDot,LorenzDZDot,e1x,e1y,e1z,dt)
        # Evolve tangent vector for next LCE (LCE2)
        e2x,e2y,e2z = TangentFlowRKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzDXDot,LorenzDYDot,LorenzDZDot,e2x,e2y,e2z,dt)
        # Evolve tangent vector for last LCE
        e3x,e3y,e3z = TangentFlowRKThreeD(sigma,R,b,xState,yState,zState,\
            LorenzDXDot,LorenzDYDot,LorenzDZDot,e3x,e3y,e3z,dt)
    # Normalize the tangent vector
    d = sqrt(e1x*e1x + e1y*e1y + e1z*e1z)
    e1x /= d
    e1y /= d
    e1z /= d
    # Accumulate the first tangent vector's length change factor
    LCE1 += log(d)
    # Pull-back: Remove any e1 component from e2
    dote1e2 = e1x * e2x + e1y * e2y + e1z * e2z
    e2x -= dote1e2 * e1x
    e2y -= dote1e2 * e1y
    e2z -= dote1e2 * e1z
    # Normalize second tangent vector
    d = sqrt(e2x*e2x + e2y*e2y + e2z*e2z)
    e2x /= d
    e2y /= d
    e2z /= d
    # Accumulate the second tangent vector's length change factor
    LCE2 += log(d)
    # Pull-back: Remove any e1 and e2 components from e3
    dote1e3 = e1x * e3x + e1y * e3y + e1z * e3z
    dote2e3 = e2x * e3x + e2y * e3y + e2z * e3z
    e3x -= dote1e3 * e1x + dote2e3 * e2x
    e3y -= dote1e3 * e1y + dote2e3 * e2y
    e3z -= dote1e3 * e1z + dote2e3 * e2z
    # Normalize third tangent vector
    d = sqrt(e3x*e3x + e3y*e3y + e3z*e3z)
    e3x /= d
    e3y /= d
    e3z /= d
    # Accumulate the third tangent vector's length change factor
    LCE3 += log(d)

# Convert to per-iterate, per-second LCEs and to base-2 logs
IntegrationTime = dt * float(nItsPerPB) * float(nIterates)
LCE1 = LCE1 / IntegrationTime
LCE2 = LCE2 / IntegrationTime
LCE3 = LCE3 / IntegrationTime
# Calculate contraction factor, for comparison.
#   For Lorenz ODE, we know this is independent of (x,y,z).
#   Otherwise, we'd have to estimate it along the trajectory, too.
Contraction = LorenzODETrJac(sigma,R,b,0.0,0.0,0.0)

# Choose a pair of coordinates from (x,y,z) to show
# Setup the parametric plot:
xlabel('x(t)') # set x-axis label
ylabel('y(t)') # set y-axis label
# Construct plot title
LCEString = '(%g,%g,%g)' % (LCE1,LCE2,LCE3)
PString = '($\sigma$,R,b) = (%g,%g,%g)' % (sigma,R,b)
CString = 'Contraction = %g, Diff = %g' % (Contraction,abs(LCE1+LCE2+LCE3-Contraction))
FString   = 'Fractal dimension = %g' % FractalDimension3DODE(LCE1,LCE2,LCE3)
title('4th order Runge-Kutta Method: Lorenz ODE at ' + PString + ':\n LCEs = ' + LCEString + ', ' + CString + '\n ' + FString)
axis('equal')
axis([-20.0,20.0,-20.0,20.0])
# Plot the trajectory in the phase plane
plot(x,y,'b')
axhline(0.0,color = 'k')
axvline(0.0,color = 'k')

# Use command below to save figure
#savefig('LorenzODELCE', dpi=600)

# Display the plot in a window
show()
```

I tried and used alot of time to do it but got lost at some point. Here is what I tried

```
%matplotlib inline  
#%matplotlib notebook
#%pylab
from matplotlib import use
#use("Qt5Agg")
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from cmath import*
from numpy import linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy import signal
import scipy as scp
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, odeint
import pandas as pd 
from scipy import linalg as LA
import nolds


# The Lorenz 3D ODEs
#Original parameter values: (sigma,R,b) = (10,28,-8/3)

def Lorenz_Jac(t,X, sigma,R,b):
    LzJac=np.array([[-sigma, sigma,     0],
         [R-z,    -1,    -x],
           [y,     x, -b]])
    
    return LzJac
  


def LorenzFun(t,X,sigma,R,b):
    x,y,z=X
    dxdt= sigma * (-x + y)
    dydt=R*x - x*z - y
    dzdt=b*z + x*y
    return[dxdt,dydt,dzdt] 



# The tangent space (linearized) flow (aka co-tangent flow)
def LorenzDXDot(t,X,dxyz,sigma,R,b):
    x,y,z=X
    dx,dy,dz=dxyz
    return[sigma * (-dx + dy),(R-z)*dx - dy - x*dz,y*dx + x*dy + b*dz]

# Volume contraction given by
# Trace(Jacobian(x,y,z)) = b - sigma - 1
def LorenzODETrJac(sigma,R,b,X):
    x,y,z=X
    tr=b - sigma - 1
    return tr
# As a check, we must have total contraction = Sum of LCEs
# Tr(J) = Sum_i LCEi
# Numerical check: at (sigma,R,b) = (10,28,-8/3)
# LCE0  ~   0.9058
# LCE1  ~   0.0000
# LCE2  ~ -14.572
# Tr(J) ~ -13.6666
# These use base-2 logs

# The fractal dimension from the LCEs (Kaplan-Yorke conjecture)
#   Assume these are ordered: LCE1 >= LCE2 >= LCE3
def FractalDimension3DODE(LCE1,LCE2,LCE3):
    # "Close" to zero ... we're estimating here
    Err = 0.01
    if LCE1 < -Err:   # Stable fixed point    (-,-,-)
        return 0.0
    elif abs(LCE1) <= Err:
        if LCE2 < -Err:  # Limit cycle        (0,-,-)
            return 1.0
        else:        # Torus               (0,0,-)
            return 2.0
    else:           # Chaotic attractor   (+,0,-)
        return 2.0 + (LCE1+LCE2) / abs(LCE3)

# 3D fourth-order Runge-Kutta integrator

# Tanget space flow (using fourth-order Runge-Kutta integrator)


# Simulation parameters
# Integration time step
dt = 0.01
#
# Control parameters for the Lorenz ODEs:
sigma = 10.0
R  = 28.0
b  = -8.0/3.0
# The number of iterations to throw away
nTransients = 10
# The number of time steps to integrate over
nIterates = 1000

# The main loop that generates the orbit, storing the states
X0=np.array([ 5.0,5,5])
# Iterate for some number of transients, but don't use these states

t0=0
tMax=1
t=[t0,tMax]
t_eval_pts=np.linspace(t0,tMax,10*tMax)
sol=solve_ivp(Lorenz,t,X0,method= 'RK45',t_eval= t_eval_pts,args=(sigma,R,b),jac=Lorenz_Jac,rtol=1e-08,atol=1e-08); 
x,y,z=sol.y
# Set up array of iterates and store the current state


# at each time step calculate new (x,y,z)(t)
dt=0.1
T=100
t1=[0,T]
solt = solve_ivp(Lorenz,t1,[x[-1],y[-1],z[-1] ],method= 'RK45',t_eval= np.arange(0,T,dt),args=(sigma,R,b),jac=Lorenz_Jac,rtol=1e-08,atol=1e-08) ;
xt,yt,zt=solt.y
# and append to lists
# Estimate the LCEs
# The number of iterations to throw away
nTransients = 100
# The number of iterations to over which to estimate
#  This is really the number of pull-backs
nIterates = 1000
# The number of iterations per pull-back
nItsPerPB = 10
# Initial condition
xState = 5.0
yState = 5.0 
zState = 5.0 
# Initial tangent vectors
e1 = [1.0,0,0]
e2 = [0,1,0]
e3=[0,0,1]


# Iterate away transients and let the tangent vectors align
#with the global stable and unstable manifolds

# Evolve tangent vector for maximum LCE (LCE1)


# Okay, now we're ready to begin the estimation
LCE1 = 0.0
LCE2 = 0.0
LCE3 = 0.0
for n in range(0,nIterates):
    xState,yState,zState = 
        # Evolve tangent vector for maximum LCE (LCE1)
    e1x,e1y,e1z = 
# Evolve tangent vector for next LCE (LCE2)
    e2x,e2y,e2z = 
# Evolve tangent vector for last LCE
    e3x,e3y,e3z = 
sol1= solve_ivp(Lorenz,LorenzDXDot,t,X0,method= 'RK45',t_eval= t_eval_pts,args=(sigma,R,b),jac=Lorenz_Jac,rtol=1e-08,atol=1e-08)
e1x,e1y,e1z=sol1.y
sol2= solve_ivp(Lorenz,LorenzDXDot,t,X0,method= 'RK45',t_eval= t_eval_pts,args=(sigma,R,b),jac=Lorenz_Jac,rtol=1e-08,atol=1e-08)
e2x,e2y,e2z=sol2.y
sol3= solve_ivp(Lorenz,LorenzDXDot,t,X0,method= 'RK45',t_eval= t_eval_pts,args=(sigma,R,b),jac=Lorenz_Jac,rtol=1e-08,atol=1e-08)
e3x,e3y,e3z=sol3.y

# Normalize the tangent vector

d=LA.norm(e1)
e1x /= d
e1y /= d
e1z /= d
# Accumulate the first tangent vector's length change factor
LCE1 += log(d)
# Pull-back: Remove any e1 component from e2
e2x -= np.dot(e1,e2) * e1x
e2y -= np.dot(e1,e2) * e1y
e2z -= np.dot(e1,e2) * e1z
# Normalize second tangent vector
d=LA.norm(e2)
e2x /= d
e2y /= d
e2z /= d
# Accumulate the second tangent vector's length change factor
LCE2 += log(d)
# Pull-back: Remove any e1 and e2 components from e3
e3x -= np.dot(e1,e3) * e1x  +  np.dot(e2,e3) * e2x
e3y -= np.dot(e1,e3) * e1y  +  np.dot(e2,e3) * e2y
e3z -= np.dot(e1,e3) * e1z  +  np.dot(e2,e3)* e2z
# Normalize third tangent vector
d=LA.norm(e2)
e3x /= d
e3y /= d
e3z /= d
# Accumulate the third tangent vector's length change factor
LCE3 += log(d)

# Convert to per-iterate, per-second LCEs and to base-2 logs
#IntegrationTime = dt * float(nItsPerPB) * float(nIterates)
#LCE1 = LCE1 / IntegrationTime
#LCE2 = LCE2 / IntegrationTime
#LCE3 = LCE3 / IntegrationTime
# Calculate contraction factor, for comparison.
#For Lorenz ODE, we know this is independent of (x,y,z).
#Otherwise, we'd have to estimate it along the trajectory, too.
Contraction = LorenzODETrJac(sigma,R,b,0.0,0.0,0.0)

# Choose a pair of coordinates from (x,y,z) to show
# Setup the parametric plot:
xlabel('x(t)') # set x-axis label
ylabel('y(t)') # set y-axis label
# Construct plot title
LCEString = '(%g,%g,%g)' % (LCE1,LCE2,LCE3)
PString = '($\sigma$,R,b) = (%g,%g,%g)' % (sigma,R,b)
CString = 'Contraction = %g, Diff = %g' % (Contraction,abs(LCE1+LCE2+LCE3-Contraction))
FString   = 'Fractal dimension = %g' % FractalDimension3DODE(LCE1,LCE2,LCE3)
title('4th order Runge-Kutta Method: Lorenz ODE at ' + PString + ':\n LCEs = ' + LCEString + ', ' + CString + '\n ' + FString)
axis('equal')
axis([-20.0,20.0,-20.0,20.0])
# Plot the trajectory in the phase plane
plot(x,y,'b')
axhline(0.0,color = 'k')
axvline(0.0,color = 'k')

# Use command below to save figure
#savefig('LorenzODELCE', dpi=600)

# Display the plot in a window
show()
```

Comment: It would be good if you describe a bit more why you want to rewrite this code and what you want to achieve. If it is performance it is quite simple (2 minutes or less coding work) to use numba on this example to get a speedup of 3 orders of magnitude. Also add the tags (vectorization, scipy, ...)

Comment: @ max9111 I added more info

Comment: You can find a variant that is a little more readable at https://stackoverflow.com/q/60338471/3088138, but still with RK4. I suspect that you would need to use the stepper classes directly if you want to use a different method, the steps of the QR method in-between do not fit the frame of a pure ODE solver.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I looked at that and tried it but It didn't work well and I cant use the scipy solver either in that code and the results I got for my system was not reasonable at all.

Comment: Maybe you could explain more what is "the point" you are stuck on, what is unexpected about your result and what would you rather see instead?

Comment: There was a more recent discussion on the topic using the same Lorenz example in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/numerical-computation-of-lyapunov-exponent where I also derived a seldom-seen "organic" method that gets the exponents as solution of an extended ODE system.